# Google Drive Audio Streaming without affecting download count?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, google-drive-api, streaming

Looking to use Google Drive, storing files and having them easily streamable from my website.

I was previously using the direct google drive download link in an **HTML5 audio tag.** like so

```
<audio controls="controls">
    <source src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1nQklEicsMeGBnuk0vv6zkHtXtyGy10S-">
</audio>
```

I quickly realized that every time this loads on my page, It marks as a download and I quickly run into Google Drive Download limits.

I was looking into using **iframes** of the preview link as an alternative, but I find its player to be ugly, hard to work with, and glitchy.

Are there are any decent alternatives with can stream Google Drive stored audio **without affecting Download Counts**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there are any decent alternatives with can stream Google Drive stored audio **without affecting Download Counts**?

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, if the Google player is not suitable, then there are no alternatives.*

#### More Information:

The only method Google provides for using their platform to stream music from Drive is using the preview link method which you already mentioned - embedding the share link in an `iframe` and changing the `/view` to `/preview` in the share URL:

```html
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/<FILE-ID-GOES-HERE>/preview"></iframe>
```

By using the method provided by Google, you're using their preview player which is what gets embedded and shows up in your `HTML` page. Aside from being restriced to using this player, the issue comes down to the fact that streaming and downloading are *functionally the same thing*. Streaming simply means the data is provided in a constant flow for playback rather than set out so the whole file needs to be downloaded before it can be read.

Either way, however, ultimately, ***the file has to be downloaded to the system that is requesting the media for playback***. There is no way around this. If the Google preview player isn't suitable, then you have to stream the file to another system for playback which will use your quota.

#### References:

- [Streaming media - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_media)

#### Further Reading:

- [Transmission Control Protocol - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)
- [User Datagram Protocol - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol)

Comment: Hello, had forgotten I posted this. Thanks a bunch! ended up switching to mediafire.