# Stream video file from Google Drive without downloading

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I want to stream videos from Google Drive URLs and want to play videos on different platforms like (ROKU, APPLE TV, ANDROID TV, AWS FIRESTICK).

I uploaded files using below script and then get weblink from API response:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
# Now build our api object, thing
drive_api = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
file_metadata = {
    'name': 'big.mp4'
}
media = MediaFileUpload('big.mp4',
                        mimetype='video/mp4',
                        resumable=True)
file = drive_api.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id, name, webViewLink').execute()
web_url = file['webViewLink']
```

It returned the URL "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rcIO7l5_YtaTqYojt50rETrrisTWWWPN/view?usp=drivesdk"

But this URL is not playing on the web or any other platforms(ROKU, APPLE TV, etc.)

How can I stream video files from Google Drive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Drive Audio Streaming without affecting download count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60861396/google-drive-audio-streaming-without-affecting-download-count)

Comment: I tried to change the URL from view to preview and result is same

Comment: Google drive is a file storage service, it is not a video hosting service thats called YouTube

Comment: I want to stream video using Google account, Is there any way or any streaming service by google?

Comment: Youtube is for streaming videos, but Drive is not a tool for that

Comment: Is there anyway to stream YouTube videos on other video player??