# Python: split a video based on file size for streaming

Tags: python, google-drive-api, video-streaming, pydrive, pyqt6

I'm trying to figure out how to stream a video where the video is uploaded to google drive in pieces and downloaded in pieces for streaming. **How do I split the video into a file sizes of my choice before uploading?** Any module is fine as long as it's fast. **Each piece needs to be playable on it's own** using pyqt6 media player. I basically want to make [this](https://split-video.com/) but in python.

Comment: Would you just like to stream the file?

Comment: The problem is that google needs time to process some videos so idk if streaming will work

Comment: I suggest you seperate this question into two parts. Have one question asking how to stream videos from google drive (this question will give you alternatives to streaming if it's not possible). Then ask a seperate question about viewing the video on pyqt. As long as there are not questions for that already

Comment: The first question exist here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62910848/stream-video-file-from-google-drive-without-downloading but hasn't been answered for almost 2 yrs. so it seems impossible

Comment: So is it possible to play a video while it's downloading?

Comment: Most likely not. consider asking [here](https://support.google.com/drive/community?hl=en)

Comment: There may be some workaround, as the player is a youtube viewer. Good luck

Comment: So should I use youtube instead of google drive?

Comment: If you can, yes. But I meant that the website for google drive can stream files with the youtube player

Comment: Using youtube is hard cause there's a quota.

Comment: I have an idea, gonna edit my question...

Comment: What is a good file size to split into?